# Bijective function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it possible to have a bijective function between two sets if the domain is *bigger* than the co-domain, for instance, a function $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: What if I told you $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ have the same _size_?

Comment: Perfectly possible. For example there is a bijection from the natural numbers to the even natural numbers, given by $f(n)=2n$.

Comment: As pointed out by the comments above this gets into the question of what you mean by "domain > co-domain". If both of the sets are finite then it is impossible (you should try to prove it!). But $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are both countable, and have the same "size". It might be good to review what it means for a set to be finite, countable, and uncountable.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the following function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$:

$$ 0 \mapsto 0 $$
$$ 1 \mapsto 1 \hspace{2cm} 2\mapsto -1$$
$$ 3 \mapsto 2 \hspace{2cm} 4\mapsto -2$$
$$ 5 \mapsto 3 \hspace{2cm} 6\mapsto -3$$
$$ \vdots \hspace{2cm} \vdots$$

And, more generally, if $n$ is even, $n\mapsto -\frac{n}{2}$; if $n$ is odd, $n \mapsto \frac{n+1}{2}$. This function would be bijective.

The trouble is, when we begin to deal with infinite sets, *size* is no longer a tangible thing. As you can see, $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z}$, but acording to this function, both have the same *size*. We call this size **cardinality**, and we write $\#(\mathbb{N}) = \#(\mathbb{Z}) = \aleph_0$. That is, the **cardinal** of both sets is aleph sub zero. However, this is the *smallest* infinity out there (and we know it as the *countable* infinity). The cardial of, say, the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is *bigger* than the cardinal $\aleph_0$ because you can't generate a bijective function from any countable set to the reals, this is known as [Cantor's diagonal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument).

Comment: In other words,$$n\mapsto\frac{1-(2n+1)(-1)^n}4.$$

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is impossible for a bijection to be constructed between two sets with different cardinalities. In fact, that's how we figure out in math if two sets are equal in size. A bijection can be formed between two sets *if and only if* they have the same cardinalities.

The two sets ($\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$) you mentioned in your question actually have the same cardinality, since you can form a bijection between them, as in Miguel's answer.

However, if you take the two sets $\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{R}$, no matter what you try to do, no function can be formed that maps an integer to a real number that is both injective and surjective. That's how we discovered the different infinities.

It's quite an interesting topic, which I highly recommend reading about.

*EDIT* It turns out that 
$$2^{|\Bbb{Z}|}=\Bbb{R}$$
or more generally,
$$|S|<2^{|S|}$$
I guess we *both* learned something today.

Comment: The statement "A bijection can be formed between two sets if and only if they have the same cardinalities" looks like a theorem here, but it is acctually just a definition of what we mean by cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of positive integers. Consider the function $\sigma$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $\sigma(n)=(-1)^n \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N},$ where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer part of $x.$ Then $\sigma$ is also a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ onto $\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: Actually $(-1)^n\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor=\frac{1+(-1)^n(2n-1)}{4}.$